# Java - call a variable from another class

Tags: java

Within my main method I'm trying to understand how to call up a variable from a different class.

I've attempted to break it down to the most simple solution possible just so I can get my head around the logic involved.

I have two classes within my package "var":

Class 1 - Source.java

```
package var;

public class Source {

    int source1;

    class setSource{

    int source1 = 5;

}
}
```

Class 2 - Var.java

```
package var;

public class Var {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int Var;

        Var = Source.setSource();

    }

}
```

First time post here but I've spent 4 days and almost all my spare time trying to figure this out, please be gentle I'm dedicated but extremely newbie right now.  Thanks in advance, I hope I've submitted this correctly.

Comment: Please take a basic Java tutorial before attempting to write code yourself - there is next to no understanding of basic concepts shown here.

Comment: You've posted this in a proper manner, but you're seriously lacking basic Java knowledge. Stack Overflow is not the right place to gain that knowledge. Return to your books or other learning material and go through it.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I can sort of see what you were thinking but you've got some of the semantics incorrect. What you want to define is a `method`. A method takes the following structure:

```
<access modifier> <return type> <method name> (<method arguments>)
```

So for example

```
public void doSomething(String value) {
    // This is the public method that returns nothing. It is called doSomething
    // It expects a string value that it will call "value"
}
```

In your case, you want to create one of these, and you want to make a `setter` and a `getter` (or *accessor and mutator* if you're being posh).

**Your Setter**

This is just a normal method. Its purpose is to set the value of some class field. So let's define our class..

```
public class MyClass {
    private int num;
}
```

Now we've got a class `MyClass` with a field `num`. But oh no, it's `private`, so let's create a setter so that the user can update the value.. Following our formula for methods, we start with a `public` access modifier. We then define the return type, which is `void` because it returns nothing. The name of the method should follow the java naming convention, which is the word "set" followed by the name of the member and finally the value for the setter.. Or all together:

```
public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}
```

This will update the value in the class with the value that you pass in. Excellent!

**Your Getter**

Well, this is nice and simple. Following our formula, it is a method that is `public` because everyone can access it; it returns something (in this case `int`) so that is the return type; the name follows the convention of "get" followed by the name and it expects no parameters.

```
public int getNum() {
    return num;
}
```

This will return the value of `num`.

**Finally, Using them!**

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        // Create a new MyClass instance.

        myClass.setNum(4);
        // Update the value in the class with the number 4.

        System.out.println("The number is " + myClass.getNum());
        // Outputs: "The number is 4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using static calls, so you have to set this variables `public static` :

```
public static int source1;
```

and access them directly:

```
Var = Source.source1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your concepts are not well polished.

Your classes should have been like this

```
public class Source {
    private int source;
    public void setSource(int src){ // Called setter
       source = src;
    }

    public int getSource(){ // Called getter
       return source;
    }    
}
```

And

```
public class Var {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Var;
        Source source = new Source();
        source.setSource(10);
        Var = source.getSource(); // Var has value 10 in it.
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your last line should say `Var = source.getSource();`.

Comment: Also fix `getSource(int src)` method.

Comment: @whiskeyspider, I almost didn't see that one.

Comment: Copy pasting code errors. Its difficult without the IDE ... think SO should make a different text box for code that would behave like IDE ...

Comment: Perhaps. I code in Notepad++, though, so I'm pretty used to it ;) You just have to get used to not working in IDE's.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak KMN hope that day never comes ! can't get enough keys for all the shortcuts that we use !

Comment: Haha well I write in C/C++ usually and I write code on both Linux and Windows. So a simple syntax highlighter with a command line compiler is rather comfortable.

Comment: Thanks StackFlowed, this is the kind of response a newbie like me needs!  I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Source is a class, you'll need to create an object that's a member of this class and then call the method on it. Additionally, the syntax for your method call is incorrect.

```
package var;

public class Source {

    int source1 = 1;

    public void setSource(){

         source1 = 5;

    }
}
```

Then:

```
package var;

public class Var {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Source source = new Source();
        System.out.println(source.source1);

        source.setSource();
        System.out.println(source.source1);
    }

}
```

I hope that makes sense to you when you compile it and run.

(Note that Java is case sensitive. On the above example, Source is the class and source is the object).

An alternative would be to declare methods and fields as static (static methods are called directly on the class), but I would suggest you make sure you understand the basic concepts of class and object instantiation before moving on to that.

Comment: I believe your answer will not run. You should declare the setter as: `void setSource()` rather than just `void setSource` You're missing the parenthesis which distinguish it as a function. Also, it really should read, `public void setSource()` instead of receiving a default access keyword. A public class should have public methods otherwise they won't be visible outside of the package.

Comment: You're right, Spencer, thanks. (Fixed now)

Comment: No problems. I forgot to mention that the same must be done for the `int source1` variable. It will need to be declared as `public int source1`. The same reasoning applies. If it's not declared as public int source1, then any references to it outside of the package will fail. For the issue at hand, this seems like it would not be an issue, but for the sake of teaching good programming habits/practices, it really should be defined as `public`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this has been a big help for a newbie like me.  At the moment I'm still getting my head around the terminology, understanding what a "setter" is, what constitutes a "class", "method" and "object" and how they're initiated is really where I'm falling down on things.

I really appreciate your time, thank you.